# Why alias restriction in joining sets

Tags: sql

As far as I know, at least in SQL Server, we can't use an alias from a table in a set that is being used to join with that table.

In an example:

```
CREATE TABLE A (A1 int, A2 int)
CREATE TABLE B (B1 int, B2 int)
SELECT a.A2
FROM
  A as a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM B as b WHERE b.B1=a.A1) b2 ON b2.B2=a.A2
```

That query will result in an **error** because the alias *a* is being used in the set that would be joined to the table where the alias refer (*A*).

In SQL Server this could be solved using the *CROSS APPLY*, or maybe by re-writing the query. (This is **NOT** my question).

My question is: **Why does this restriction exists?**, why not let use the alias as the SQL Server *CROSS APPLY*?

My first guess is: Parallelism. If we can restrict this, each set that appear to be joined could always be computed in parallel and then joined. But it is just a guess. It could be more flexible and let me use the alias and compute dependencies between joining sets as I guess does *CROSS APPLY*.

Maybe there isn't a why :)

Comment: Because an `INNER JOIN` is not a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction exists because of the scoping rules for standard SQL.  One table in a `from` clause just doesn't know what is happening *inside* another table.  Remember, SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  The order of the tables in the `from` clause is not at all necessarily related to the actual order they are processed in.

This restriction does not apply in `SELECT`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses, because the `FROM` clause is evaluated first.

As for the `cross apply` being the same or different from a `join`.  There are many ways to write joins and the explicit `join` syntax is just one of them.  Correlated subqueries, nested queries in `select`s, `exists` with subqueries, and `in` with subqueries are all performing some variant of the relational join operation.  They are expressed differently.

The uses of `cross apply` with a subquery are also, generally, types of joins.  There may be some cases with very complex queries with nested uses of windows function where it may not be possible to rewrite the query as an explicit join.  In most cases, though, I have been able to.

Comment: Why not derive dependencies between joining sets and make the execution plan aligned with that?. The answer is just: Because is this way by design?

Comment: @PeterTimoz . . . You could say that.  But the SQL language was devised by IBM, and then popularized by Oracle in the 1980s.  It is actually based on a few principles, which tend to get lost in thousands of pages of documentation.  Some of its quirks (and power) derive from these principles.  The independence of the `from` clause elements is one of those.